# Applying filter on coherence cache object

Tags: c#, caching, oracle-coherence

I've a System.Linq.Expression object whose value is:
((FieldA == "Value1") && (FieldB == "ValueB"))

I need to be apply this expression on top a coherence cache object and return the filtered object to the calling method.

```
public object MyMethod(Expression expression)
{
    IQueryable<T>   myCoherenceCacheObject;
    var filteredCacheObject = //Filter logic here;
    return filteredCacheObject;
}
```

How do I do this please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`AndFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/java-reference/com/tangosol/util/filter/AndFilter.html) composing two [`EaqualFilters`](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/java-reference/com/tangosol/util/filter/EqualsFilter.html).
Here is code snippet assuming that you have your object cached in `POF` format:

```
private YourPofObject yourPofObject() {

    ValueExtractor extractorA = new PofExtractor(String.class, 0); // 0 - is index for fieldA property of your POF object
    ValueExtractor extractorB = new PofExtractor(String.class, 1); // 1 - is index for fieldB property of your POF object

    Filter filterAB = new AndFilter(new EqualsFilter(extractorA, "Value1"),
            new EqualsFilter(extractorB, "ValueB"));

    Set extractedEntries = namedCache.entrySet(filterAB);
    for (Object extractedEntry : extractedEntries) {
        Map.Entry<String, YourPofObject> entry = (Map.Entry<String, YourPofObject>) extractedEntry;
        return entry.getValue();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Make sure that your cache has [indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/api_querycache.htm#COHDG5322) for your POF object's `fieldA` and `fieldB`, otherwise the extracting operation might be quite slow.